# Expansion of variables / functions in Cloud Formation YAML

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to learn how to write Cloud Formation templates (in YAML) by hand.

I'm finding the iteration process quite slow and, therefore, learning by 'trial and error' also slow.

For example, I'm trying to figure out if this:

```
Fn::Join: 
    - "/"
    - - "s3:/"
      - !Ref MyBucket
      - "deviceFeed"
```

could be replaced with this:

```
!Sub "s3://${MyBucket}/deviceFeed"
```

(I have no idea of the answer to that question btw... and the answer is not what I'm asking here).

Is there someway that I can quickly run my YAML through a process to expand out functions like these and see the final rendered strings etc? Perhaps something in the CLI or console? At the moment I'm just deploying the stacks and trawling through the errors, then guessing the mistake. My pace is glacial on a particularly cold day. I need a way to move faster.

Any tips greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using native CloudFormation or some meta tool, such as SAM or serverless framework?

Comment: Unfortunately, the rendered values are dynamic at runtime so aren't actually known, in the general case, until some pre-requisite resource has actually been created. Be aware of helpful tools, however, such as cfn-lint, cfn-nag, the validate-template feature of awscli, and generally the --dry-run feature of the awscli (not sure how helpful it is here tbh).

Comment: @jarmod, this is straight CF templates. I have played with SAM though which I quite liked and also the CDK via TypeScript which I found very productive. This task I'm currently on is essentially ejecting the CDK work into straight CF to integrate into the existing pipeline (rightly or wrongly, that's the direction we're taking)

Answer (score 1):

I do not have 50+ reputation points, so I'm leaving an answer. That being said...

First:

```yaml
!Sub "s3://${MyBucket}/deviceFeed"
```

This is perfectly correct and even better than Fn::Join in plain YAML CloudFormation templates. !Ref to MyBucket would return the name of the bucket.

[Reference on S3 Buckets return values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html#aws-properties-s3-bucket-return-values)

Second:

CloudFormation doesn't provide a feature like terraform's plan command. And as @jarmod said, !Ref's to resources created in the template will only return values after creation. A way to have a dry run report, is creating changesets... The changeset will show you what will change in your stack, but won't help much if there are errors in the template as it doesn't run deep lint checks on the yaml file.

[Here's an article that goes deep in to cloudformation changesets](https://medium.com/boltops/a-simple-introduction-to-cloudformation-part-4-change-sets-dry-run-mode-c14e41dfeab7)